# How do i give a Wordpress editor access to the Site Kit by Google plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

In WordPress I give some users a certain role (admin, editor etc). These users have by default not access to the [Site Kit by Google](https://sitekit.withgoogle.com/) plugin. Do you know an option how I can turn this on?

Maybe a code in functions.php? and I don't want to add a new plugin like user roles.

Answer (score 1):

edit permissions.php  , plugins->google-site-kit->inlucdes->core->permissions->permissions.php

```
$this->primitive_to_core = array(
            // By default, only allow administrators to authenticate.
             //self::AUTHENTICATE        => 'manage_options', 
            self::AUTHENTICATE        => 'edit_others_posts',

            // Allow contributors and up to view their own post's insights.
            self::VIEW_POSTS_INSIGHTS => 'edit_posts',

            // Allow editors and up to view the dashboard and module details.
            self::VIEW_DASHBOARD      => 'edit_others_posts',
            self::VIEW_MODULE_DETAILS => 'edit_others_posts',

            // Allow administrators and up to manage options and set up the plugin.
            //self::MANAGE_OPTIONS      => 'manage_options',
            //self::SETUP               => 'manage_options',
            self::MANAGE_OPTIONS      => 'edit_others_posts',
            self::SETUP               => 'edit_others_posts',

            // Allow to differentiate between authors and contributors.
            self::PUBLISH_POSTS       => 'publish_posts',
        );
```

Comment: ah so Google did not consider other user types. a downside to this is that every update will overwrite this and you have to do it all over again.